# What is the convention to specify data types of attributes in apiary.io markdown?

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io, apiary

The apiary.io list resource attributes in point form. Is there a specific convention to show what data type these attributes are, or met data specifying formats?

Comment: Are you referring to resource attributes – properties of a resource or to a particular HTTP message-body (request / response) attributes?

Comment: I'm looking to state the datatype for each resource attribute. I'd also like to offer additional information. Imagine a attribute called "ip", which would be a string, I'd like to also state that it can be a ipv4 or ipv6 address.

All of which is easy to do in markdown, but I'm wondering if there is a convention, that can possibly add more value. Thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is not convention for discussing resource's attributes in the API Blueprint. What comes close is **planned** [Message-body Attributes Description](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/25).

But I feel what would be the real solution is what the concept of a future API Blueprint – [Resource Blueprint](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/tree/resource-blueprint) proposes under *semantic data definition* (of a resource). Refer to the [example resource blueprint](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/resource-blueprint/examples/Gist%20API.md#attributes).

So while none of the previous is implemented, if you are looking for a convention, I would suggest consider the one as proposed in resource blueprint e.g.:

```
# Resource [/resource]

## Attributes

+ ip (string) ... ipv4 or ipv6 address associated with the resource
+ some-other-attribute (number, optional, `42`) ... a number of something
```

Comment: Thank you, you answered my specific question on convention/syntax for modelling resource attribute data types.

You also answered questions I did not ask, how to model state machines. This is, or I should be say _will be_ awesome. I'm delighted to see the modelling of state-machines. 

I'm looking forward to the Resource Blueprint support being added. Hopefully that will be soon.